# File upload not working using codeigniter. Have no idea why

Tags: php

I am trying to add an, upload an image to a directory in my root. When I hit the submit button for the add image it shows the error in the if statement as if it was false.
I have no idea what I am doing wrong.

To see what I have live visit here:  http://travismichael.net/SeniorProject

I have my uploads folder in my root and i made it writable.

Here is my Controller

```
function do_upload() {
$config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
$config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
$config['max_size'] = '32';
$config['max_width']  = '200';
$config['max_height']  = '200';

$this->load->library('upload', $config);

if ( !$this->upload->do_upload('userfile'))
{
  echo  '<p>IMAGE NOT WORKING</p>';
}
else
{
  $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

  $this->load->view('partials/upload_success', $data);
}
```

Here is my View

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php $this->load->view('partials/page_head'); ?> 
<body>
<body class="home">
<div id="container">
<div id="top">
  <div class="topcenter">
    <h2><a class="addbtn">Add Folder</a></h2>
    <h2><a class="deletebtn" href="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/home/delete">DeleteFolders</a></h2>
  </div>    
  <div class="navdescription"><span>Home</span></div>
</div>

  <div class="projectFolders">
  <?php foreach($foldername as $row) { ?>
    <div class="folder <?php echo $row->folderName; ?>">
      <button class="<?php echo $row->folderName; ?>"><?php echo $row->folderName; ?>    </button>
    </div>
    <script>
        $(function () {
          $('button.<?php echo $row->folderName; ?>').bind('click', 
            function() { $('.open.<?php echo $row->folderName;?>').show() });

          $('.gohome').bind('click', 
            function() { $('.open.<?php echo $row->folderName;?>').hide() });
        });
    </script>
  <?php } ?>

 <?php foreach($foldername as $row) { ?>
    <div class="open <?php echo $row->folderName; ?>">
      <h1><?php echo $row->folderName;?></h1>
      <a class="gohome">Home</a><a class="addimagebtn">Add Image</a>
        <div class="edititable" contenteditable="true" focus="true">
          Your Content Goes Here
        </div>
    </div>
  <?php } ?>
  <div class="uploadimage">
    <?php echo form_open_multipart('home/do_upload');?>
      <input type="file" name="userfile" size="20" />
      <br /><br />
      <input type="submit" value="Add Image" />
     </form>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div id="bottom">
  <div class="formWrapper">
    <form accept-charset="utf-8" method="post" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/home/create" id="cf_form">
      <input type="text" name="folderName" placeholder="Enter new Folder" class="required" required/>
    <?php echo form_submit('createFolder', 'Create Folder'); ?>
    <?php echo form_close(); ?>
    <?php echo validation_errors('<p class="error">'); ?>
</div>
</div>  
</div><!-- End of container div -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what do you get in  $this->upload->display_errors()? -- add this to see --  `echo  '<p>IMAGE NOT WORKING</p>'.$this->upload->display_errors();`

Answer (score 0):

Some reason Codeignitor forgot to update their Documentation.

You need to add this line right above where you call the upload library

$this->upload->initialize($config);